Changing Definition of Latex Macro in VSCode Jupyter Results in Error
I can use latex in jupyter markdown cells in vscode, e.g.
$$
\newcommand{\testVar}{y}
\testVar
$$

This works as intended on the first glance. I can define a macro in a cell and also use it in subsequent cells. However, if I change sth in the cell where the macro is defined, e.g.
$$
\newcommand{\testVar}{y}
\testVar + 1
$$ 

i get the error
ParseError: KaTeX parse error: \newcommand{\testVar} attempting to redefine \testVar; use \renewcommand

Thus, KaTex, apparently used by VSCode, seems to have a global variable space which does not allow redefinition. Reexecuting the cell without changing it does not trigger the error. Supposedly, KaTex detects that nothing has changed and doesn't recompute the cell. When changing the latex cell, the only way to not get the error is to close the VSCode tab and reopen it again. Notably, restarting the kernel and clearing all outputs, does NOT fix the problem. They seem not to trigger rerendering of the latex cells at all, so this makes sense.
This is rather unpractical, because it does basically prohibit you to develop macros on the fly without closing and reopening the notebook all the time. Does anyone know a solution to this? I imagine what could help would be a way to restart KaTex engine in VSCode (?) However, I guess this is not possible from jupyter itself.
